# What does と and なり mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, manga

The whole sentence is:

> 私**となりに**住んでおります綾瀬と申します

It's from the manga yotsubato, that I'm trying to read along with a translated version. The translated one says "I live right next door. We're the Ayase residence"

So I couldn't find anything conclusive about this なり word, and I also don't know about this と, if it's part of the same expression, or a separate particle, and if it is, I don't know the role it's playing here. Could you please clarify?

Comment: that's one word... the kanji is [隣]{となり}...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confused because you are trying to distinguish と　and なり while it is just a single word: となり, or 隣 in kanji, that means "neighbor/next to (as in living next door)". This should clarify your doubt I hope.

Comment: Thanks! When I put the sentence in jisho.org their system separated と from なり so that caused the confusion. I should have tried to search for them together.

Comment: It seems like there should be a pause or a は after 私 in the example sentence. Maybe that's why jisho.org didn't parse it as expected.

Comment: Yeah actually I was thinking the same thing.